# How can you turn a stream into a downloadable file in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

How do i go from a readstream to a res.download() without writing the file to storage first?

Comment: where you got your readstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` itself is a WriteStream, so you can simply `.pipe` into it.
You'll have to set appropriate `Content-*` headers as well though.

```
app.get('/stream', (req, res, next) => {
  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'some/type',
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${file_name}"`,
  });
  readstream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!